# htaccess redirect if domain not equals to .. And domain doesn't equal to

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect

I'm trying to put both conditions in one line..

I want to change domain name to example.com if visitor came from any another url **except for exampl2.com**

that means if i came from *example3.com/blah/blah* it should be -> *example.com/blah/blah*
and if i came from *example2.com/blah/blah* **it should stay the same**

I have the first part done

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R]
```

This one says if website is not www.example.com or example.com then change domain to example.com
How do i exclude *example2.com* from this and keep it as it is without changing to any other domain ?

Comment: @faa I just added more explanation at the bottom, hope you get what i mean now, i said if you came from example4 or 5 or anything then redirect to example.com BUT if you came from example2 then dont redirect

Comment: As I said, this `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example2\.com$ [NC]`  **EXCLUDES** example2.com from the rule. The `!` means DON'T APPLY THE NEXT RULE IF THE FOLLOWING STRING IS PRESENT. That's what you are asking for.

Comment: Ah i got what you mean now, you should have mentioned that this line will only be appended and not replaced with the original one... You may post this in the answer to get your bounty :)